# Why do l get parser error when trying to run the whole folder, but not if I run 1 file at a time?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I currently have a folder containing more than 100,000 xml files. I wrote a function that parses xml data. This function uses xmltodict package.

```
def parse_xml(file_path):
    with open(file_path,'rb') as f:
        dict_data = xmltodict.parse(f.read())
```

This function works when I copy and paste each individual file's name into the function. I'm trying to write a function that will direct and parse the whole folder without manually typing each name.

```
for files in os.listdir('/Users/dp/Dropbox/Data/Moody-xbrl'):
    parse_xml(files)
```

Running the code gives me

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xmltodict.py", line 378, in parse
    parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

Why does this happen and what should I do to resolve it?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen if you pass a directory path to `xmltodict`?  You need to iterate over the files and pass each one to `xmltodict`.

Comment: The likelihood is that you are selecting some files (for example, directories or system/hidden files) that are not XML, and attempting to parse these.

Comment: Can you print(files) and show the file names before parsing? This way you know which file it is choking on.